# Enable remote connections to sql express with a script

Tags: c#, deployment, database-connection, sql-server-express

I am deploying an application with sql server express 2008. In the prerequisites section of my application I have included:

[image]

As a result when a user installs my application it will install sql express as well.

Then I will be able to connect to that database engine as:

```
        try
        {
            // database should be in the same network
            SqlConnection conn =
                new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress; Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection succesfull");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect");
        }
```

---

Now when I install a different application(client version) I will like to be able to connect to that database engine. I managed to connect to it by doing something like:

```
        try
        {

            SqlConnection conn =
                new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.0.120\sqlexpress,22559; USER=sa; PASSWORD=*********");
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection succesfull");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect");
        }
```

In order for that code to work I had to do the following:

[image]

[image]

---

### So my question is:

How could I configure this with code? When I deploy my application I want my application to install sql express like it does but I also whant to enable tcp/IP connections, enable some ports and lastly create a password for the account "SA" because I am not able to connect to the database remotly if the sa account does not have a password.

Or maybe I am asking to much and I am doing the wrong thing. perhaps I should do all this just for the database that I am planing on deploying not the database engine. whatever is easier. I have had a hard time deploying this maybe it will be eassier to deoploy a local database along with a wcf service in order to create CRUD operations on the local database remotely.

### EIDT

I found this 3 links that claim on doing something similar and I still cannot make it work.

1) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839980

2) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/c7d3c3af-2b1e-4273-afe9-0669dcb7bd02/

3) http://www.sql-questions.com/microsoft/SQL-Server/34211977/can-not-connect-to-sql-2008-express-on-same-lan.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

downloaded sql server express 2008 (SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe) and place it in the root of my c drive. then I install it with the following parameters:

C:\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe /q /hideconsole /action=Install /features=SQL /instancename=SQLEXPRESS /enableranu=1 /sqlsvcaccount="NT Authority\Network Service" /AddCurrentUserAsSqlAdmin /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck /TCPENABLED=1

I add /TCPENABLED=1  in order to enable TCP/IP

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to create modified `bootstrapper package` to install Sql Server 2005 Express with customzation.

As an alternative, you can also use a custom action in your installer to change the targeted server using SMO.

Something like this:

```
Server server = new Server( "ServerName\\InstanceName" ); 
server.ConnectionContext.Connect();
server.Settings.LoginMode = ServerLoginMode.Mixed;
server.Settings.Alter();
```

We use SMO object to create user login and associate user to our created application database.. even run sql script to create database if database is not available..

Refer these links:
[Configuring SQL Express During Installation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/09/20/configuring-sql-express-during-installation.aspx)
[Configuring SQL Server when included as a requirement](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/1557dea8-1054-4895-bc3e-f2ced23582da/)

Note: Create your sql server connection string settings in App.config file rather than putting hardcore in code.. this will help you customize application first run customization e.g. database creation.

Answer (score 1):

These might be of some help, I've had it on my todo list for a while for the computers I have to setup for my app to run with Sql Server 2008 Express.  It's basically a way to setup a script that the SQL08exp installer will read and automate a lot of the setup according to what you set in the script.

http://digitalformula.net/articles/how-to-perform-an-unattended-installation-of-sql-server-2008-express/

http://blogesh.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/silent-install-of-sql-server-2008/

Comment: When I deploy my application sql express may already be installed so I am required to do this on a machine that has sql server express installed. Thanks for the help